# Why do I get FileIOPermission exception while opening Chromedriver c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, selenium-chromedriver

I am working in a Windows_Form project where the very first operation is set some ChromeOptions and open chrome-driver. My project have been working perfectly for 3 months. However, it gave me today the next exception while debugging my project:

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.*

Here is my code, I got the exception in the line:
"driver = new ChromeDriver(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Resources\", chromeOptions);"

```
    public partial class PJX_MainWindow : Form
    {
        private ChromeDriver driver;
        private ChromeOptions chromeOptions;

        private void PJX_MainWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", @"C:\PJX\SalesReports");
            chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
            chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");

            driver = new ChromeDriver(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Resources\", chromeOptions);
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

            string url = "https://www.somepage.com";
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        }
    }
```

I guess it is something related with permissions in the folder, I already set the right permissions either in the folder and chromedriver.exe

Thank you so much in advance for your help.
(sorry for bad English, I am not a native speaker :)  )

Comment: How is your program being launched? That error only happens when you are running code in a sand-boxed environment with low privileges.

Comment: Hi Scott, thank you for your response. Yes it is running like that. It is using the security and certificates which my company has in the intranet. I rarely set some security because these reasons. I was reading about this issue and I found about something relative with the CAS. Do you now something about it? cheers